# How to say "No, me!" in German?

Tags: vocabulary, grammaticality

I try to use German instead of English sometimes when I write a caption of my photo. I want to type something funny. Is the following caption right?

In English:

> Very tasty! ー The food? ー No, me!

In German:

> Sehr lecker! ー Das Essen? ー Nein, mir!

Comment: The first and the second are definitely correct. The third is a matter of context, it also could be "Nein, ich!". What is the question of this photo, you want to answer with its caption?

Comment: I am so confused about how to use "me" in German. I do not between "ich"' or "mir" is correct.

I want to say: "I am delicious." I just want to make the sentence funny.

Comment: @IQV: In what context would *mir* be correct?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper e. g. "Nein, (das gehört) mir!".

Comment: That means the one I wrote is correct, right?

Comment: @lvlakmild Now I understand your question. Sorry, needed some time. I thought you speak about three photos, but it's only one. No "ich" is correct: "Sehr lecker! ー Das Essen? ー Nein, ich!"

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciated it!
I am so confused because: "ich" means I - "mir" means me. So, if I write directly when I translate it from English. I will write mir, but I know there are Dative and Akkusative in German that makes me so confused.

Comment: @IQV: I don't understand how "Nein, das gehört mir!" can make any sense in the little dialogue given by the OP. What does possession have to do with tastiness?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It does make no sense. I understood the question of the OP wrong (see my other comment). I didn't see, that the caption is one little dialogue.

Comment: Actually, German is more logical than English in this specific example - The case is nominative, but English speakers for some reason tend to use the pronoun "I" in accusative (i.e. "me"). Note this is even wrong in English, but often used.

Comment: @tofro, I think that calling this wrong in English would be overly prescriptive. But I agree that English grammar is confused in this case.

Comment: @CarstenS Check here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/should-i-put-myself-last-me-and-my-friends-vs-my-friends-and-me-or-my-fri - It's common, but a common mistake

Comment: @tofro, ok you just have more prescriptive views than I then, that's ok. That English question is about a different but related phenomenon (I could have followed many native speakers and written phenomena;), though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is

> Sehr lecker! ー Das Essen? ー Nein, **ich**!

Why? You must ask "**Wer oder Was** ist lecker?". The answer: "**Ich**". (1. Fall, Nominativ)
If you can ask "**Wem** gehört das Essen?". The answer: "**Mir**". (3. Fall, Dativ)
 
And finally "**Wen oder Was** hat das überzeugt?". The answer: "**Mich**" (4. Fall Akkusativ)

Comment: @Dustin To be honest, my German A1 level is going rusty fast but I am trying my best to brush up it again. So, I am still confused about Nominativ, Dativ and Akkusativ. I do not sure which and when is be used in any context.

Comment: "You must ask" is nice for native speakers, but totally useless for non-native or at least non-fluent speakers. If you don't know that it should be nominative, you don't know what to ask either. So "you must ask" works well for native kids in schools, but otherwise, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

The first and the second part are correct. The third must be "ich":

> Sehr lecker! ー Das Essen? ー Nein, ich!

Comment: And OP's sentences is wrong. *Das Essen?* is a question in nominative, and the answer should also be in nominative, whence *ich*.